# Java how to check what classes are visible to a specific classloader at runtime

Tags: java, classloader

Is there a way to know what classes are visible to a specific classloader at runtime?

Comment: Can you be more specific? E.g. are you talking about loaded classes or potentially loadable classes?

Comment: I am talking about classes that are visible to a classloader so it should be potentially loadable classes to a specific classloader.

Comment: Then, the answer must be no, not in general. Only in specific circumstances, i.e. when the particular loader maps class names to some sort of filesystem that you can traverse in advance (and all loaders it might delegate to, do something similar). A counter example would be something as simple as a `URLClassLoader` when you add an `http:` URL.